# Checking for multicollinearity in selection of variables for regression model

Tags: correlation, data-transformation, multicollinearity, predictor, variance-inflation-factor

For the selection of variables for a regression model, I did a pairwise correlation matrix between the different predictors and the response variable. From the pairwise correlation matrix, I realise there could be a linearity relationship between the log transformed predictors and the response variable. I would like to ask if it is better to check for multicollinearity by using the vif function in R after transforming the predictors or just simply check for multicollinearity on the independent variables?

Also, my response variable is symmetric after I log transformed it. Is it a sensible decision in doing so before checking for multicollinearity? Any advice or suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CV.

First, for collinearity, I think condition indexes and proportion of variance explained is a better method than VIF.

Second, to your question, I think you should check for collinearity on the variables as they would be in the model.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the advice. So you are implying that simply checking for multicollinearity between IVs would be a more sensible decision rather than transforming the IVs before checking for multicollinearity?

Comment: I am saying that you should check for collinearity with the variables in the form they will be in in the regression - maybe transformed, maybe not.  The decision of whether to transform should be made on a substantive basis prior to doing the analysis.